# Formula and its inverse in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, inverse

I'm trying to implement ad easy function in Excel.
I want the user input a value in the cell A1, and in the cell A2 the function should be "The value in A1"+1.
This is a super easy task in Excel, but I really need a different behavior: when the user inputs a value in A2, Excel should compute "The value in A2"-1 and put this value in A1 (the inverse formula of the previous one).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that the user should be able to enter values in either A1 or A2? And depending on where he enters the value, the other cell should have the answer?

Comment: @BuzzLightyear Yes, that's right.

Comment: You'll need to use VBA to do it. It would create a [Circular Reference](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/circular-reference.html) otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following Event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range, A2 As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    Set A2 = Range("A2")

    If Intersect(Union(A1, A2), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Not Intersect(A1, Target) Is Nothing Then
            A2.Value = A1.Value + 1
        Else
            A1.Value = A2.Value - 1
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**